# some problems were encountered while processing the POMs: [error] non resolvable import POM

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jersey

I want to start a new Jersey project but I failed in the first step because pom.xml show some errors and the project can't be built. 
the error :

```
some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[error] non resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.glassfish.jersey: jersey-bom:pom...."
```

Here is my pom.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>JERSEYProject</groupId>
 <artifactId>JERSEYProject</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>simple-service-webapp</name>

<build>
    <finalName>simple-service-webapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Can you please help me to fix this problem? I tried a lot of configurations but none of theme worked. I don't know if I had problem on my IDE configuration (IntelliJ).
Thank you!!

Comment: try to write the hole error please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the version of the glassfish.Either directly or as variable with the given name `jersey.version`